# Paypal Third Party Shopping Cart with IPN

Tags: php, paypal, e-commerce

Im have project about an e-commerce site where in carshop and car owners can register and create buy-sell transactions. I have already figured out how to process the payment (buyer=car owner, and seller=carshop). But I have no idea how to get the transaction informations(from paypal to my server ) so i can save it to my data base.(eg. transaction id).

here's my code on the shopping cart of the car owner:

```
<div id="confrm-body">
<label> Summary of Service Requests:</label><br/>
<label>Services in your cart has been categorized by   the shops the offer them. Please pay each service request respectively.</label>
<br/><label>Check out:0/3</label>   <br/>
<?php get_sum_cart($_SESSION['cid']);?>
 </div>
```

and here are the functions:

```
  <?php
function get_sum_cart($cid){
        $q_get_sum_cart="select distinct(tbl_cart.shop_id),shop_name from tbl_services,tbl_carshop,tbl_cart where tbl_cart.svc_id=tbl_services.svc_id
        and tbl_cart.shop_id=tbl_carshop.shop_id and tbl_cart.client_id='". $cid ."'";
        $get_sum_result=mysql_query($q_get_sum_cart);

        while($sum_row=mysql_fetch_array($get_sum_result)){
            $shop_id=$sum_row['shop_id'];
            $shop_name=$sum_row['shop_name'];   
            ?>
            <form action=<?php echo cart_url;?> method="post" > 
            <table class="tbl_summary">

                <tr>
                    <th colspan="6"><label class="h-lbl"><?php echo $shop_name?></label> <a id="<?php echo $shop_id?>" class="client-btn" href="#">Show/Hide</a></th>
                </tr>
                <div id="slide">
                <tbody class="tbl_summary_cont <?php echo $shop_id?>">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col" class="sub-th" style="width:100px;"><label>Preview</label></th>
                    <th scope="col" class="sub-th" style="width:210px;"><label>Pacakage/Kit Name</label></th>
                    <th scope="col" class="sub-th" style="width:100px;"><label>Initial Charge</label></th>
                    <th scope="col" class="sub-th" style="width:100px;"><label>Tax</label></th>
                    <th scope="col" class="sub-th" style="width:110px;"><label>Payable</label></th>
                    <th scope="col" class="sub-th" style="width:150px;"><label>Date Added</label></th>

                <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo get_carshop_paypal($shop_id);?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
                <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
                <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="https://localhost/test-ipn/">
                <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="<?php echo cart_currency;?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="<?php echo cart_country;?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo return_url;?>">

                </tr>

                <?php make_sum_tbl($shop_id,$cid);?>



                <tfoot>
                    <td colspan="6"><input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" value=""> 

                    <div class="lbl_bill">

                        <?php $sub_total = sum_per_tbl($shop_id,$cid);?>
                        <label>Sub-total:<span>Php <?php echo number_format($sub_total,2);?></span></label>
                        <label>Discount:<span><?php echo $discount;?></span></label>
                        <label>Total:<span>Php <?php echo get_discount($sub_total);?></span></label>

                        </div>
                    </td>

                </tfoot>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </form> 
            <?php   
            $o_t=$o_t + $sub_total;


        }
?>
                <label>Over-all Total of Payables:<span>Php <?php echo number_format($o_t,2);?></span></label>
<?php       

}

function make_sum_tbl($shop_id,$cid){
    $q_get_tbl="select cart_id,tbl_cart.svc_id,kit_name,material_fee,svc_fee,t_amnt,tax,shop_name,tbl_cart.date from tbl_services,tbl_carshop,tbl_cart where tbl_cart.svc_id=tbl_services.svc_id and tbl_cart.shop_id=tbl_carshop.shop_id
    and tbl_cart.client_id='".$cid."' and tbl_carshop.shop_id='".$shop_id."'";
    $get_tbl_result=mysql_query($q_get_tbl);
    $n=1;
    while($tbl_row=mysql_fetch_array($get_tbl_result)){
        ?>
            <tr class="<?php echo $class;?>">
            <td><label><img class="min-prev" src="<?php echo get_service_pic($tbl_row['svc_id']);?>"></label></td>
            <input type="hidden" name="item_number_<?php echo $n;?>" value="<?php echo $tbl_row['svc_id'];?>">
            <td><label><?php echo $tbl_row['kit_name'];?></label></td>
            <input type="hidden" name="item_name_<?php echo $n;?>" value="<?php echo $tbl_row['kit_name'];?>">
            <td><label><?php echo $tbl_row['material_fee']+$tbl_row['svc_fee'];?></label></td>
            <td><label><?php echo $tbl_row['tax'];?>%</label></td>  
            <td><label>Php<?php echo number_format($tbl_row['t_amnt'],2);?></label></td>
            <input type="hidden" name="amount_<?php echo $n;?>" value="<?php echo $tbl_row['t_amnt'];?>">
            <td><label><?php echo $tbl_row['date'];?></label></td>
            <td><label><?php echo $row['total'];?></label></td>
            </tr>
        <?php
        $n++;
    }
}
function sum_per_tbl($shop_id,$cid){
    $sum_q="select sum(t_amnt) as total from tbl_services,tbl_carshop,tbl_cart where tbl_cart.svc_id=tbl_services.svc_id and tbl_cart.shop_id=tbl_carshop.shop_id and tbl_cart.client_id='".$cid."' and tbl_carshop.shop_id='".$shop_id."'";
    $sum_result=mysql_query($sum_q);
    while($sum=mysql_fetch_array($sum_result)){
        $t=$sum['total'];
        }
        return $t;
    }


function get_discount($sub_total){
$disc=0;

$total=number_format($sub_total - ($sub_total * $disc),2);
return $total;
}   
?>
```

HERE IS THE CONFIG FILE:

```
function get_carshop_paypal($shop_id){
$get_p_add= "select pay_pal from tbl_carshop_paypal where shop_id='".$shop_id."'";
$result=mysql_query($get_p_add);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $shop_paypal=$row['pay_pal'];

}
return $shop_paypal;
}
define('base_url','http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/');
define('cart_currency','PHP');
define('cart_country','PH');
define('cart_url','https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr');
define('return_url',base_url.'/occs/accounts/client/index.php?p=con-transact&make='.$make.'&year='.$year.'&model='.$model);
```

AND here is what im trying to combine(IPN_handler):

```
class Paypal_IPN
{

    private $_url;


    public function __construct($mode = 'live')
    {
        if ($mode == 'live')
        $this->_url = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';

        else
        $this->_url = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
    }

    public function run()
    {
        $postFields = 'cmd=_notify-validate';



        foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
        {   
            $postFields .= "&$key=".urlencode($value);

        }

        $ch = curl_init();

            curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $this->_url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
            CURLOPT_POST => true,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postFields
        ));

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        $fh = fopen('result.txt', 'w');
        fwrite($fh, $result . ' -- ' . $postFields);
        fclose($fh);

        echo $postFields;
    }
}?>
```

can you guys give me idea about how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

All you would need to do is customize that IPN library to include your own database inserts, and then make sure IPN was enabled in your PayPal account profile.  You can also use notify_url in your button code to override the profile setting, but I like to setup my profile as a default IPN listener.

You might be interested in my [PHP template for PayPal IPN](http://www.angelleye.com/download-angell-eye-paypal-ipn-template/).  It's pretty popular, and while it could be re-developed as an object-oriented class (which I plan to do) it works great as-is and provides you with a working IPN solution that logs all IPN in your database.

I use it for nearly all of my projects.  Just install the IPN template (instructions included in the download) and then you can relate the IPN data back to your own data using record ID's.  For example, I always include the invoice parameter with my PayPal requests so that my local record ID is passed to PayPal.  This way it'll come back in IPN as an invoice parameter as well.  I just use this as the relationship with the existing tables for whatever project I'm working, and all of the IPN data is available to that record without any further customization.

You could have it up-and-running in about 10 min.

Comment: 1 more question: will the payer still receive an IPN even if the IPN settings of the seller was not configured as "Disabled"? I mean will the notify url will still override the IPN settings?

Comment: RE: will the payer still receive an IPN even if the IPN settings of the seller was configured as "Disabled"? I mean will the notify url will still override the IPN settings?

Comment: Yes, if notify url is included it will always trigger an IPN to the URL provided.